# UTC to Local Date Conversion Failed for Year Lesser than 1960 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timezone, internationalization

**Summary:**

I am working in a project which passing UTC datetime to the client (html) page. I want to show the local date in the UI. Here I am getting issues to get correct local time if the year is lesser than 1960.

**Environment / Windows Time zone:**

System is set the time zone with `GMT Standard Time` (UK time and now it is in day light saving).

**Sample Code:**

I am having an html page with the following code.

```html
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var utcDate = new Date("1960-04-11T23:00:00Z"); // utc date returned from server
            var localDate = new Date(utcDate);
            console.log(localDate)
            document.getElementById('dValue').innerText = localDate;
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Your Date is <span id="dValue"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Example Output:**

If you give `1960-04-11T23:00:00Z` the output is (expected one like added 1 hour)

> Your Date is Tue Apr 12 1960 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

If you give `1959-04-11T23:00:00Z` the output is (error result)

> Your Date is Tue Apr 11 1959 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (British Summer Time)

*Can anyone help on this? Why year lesser than 1960 not considering 1 hour?*

**Browser Update:**

1. Chrome - Reproduced issue
2. Firefox - Reproduced issue
3. Edge - Reproduced issue
4. Internet Explorer (win 10) - Working fine

**Update (23-04-2021) - Serverside:**

Based on Matt Johnson-Pint answer, the conversion is fine except IE. If so another interesting factor is in the server. The server side (.NET MVC) maintains the date in local time (instead of UTC and does not have any timezone info also) and the controller converts the date to UTC while sending to the UI.

Based on the answer, if my date is `12-04-1959 00:00` then UTC date also will be same. But in the C# code it returns `{4/11/1959 11:00:00 PM}`.
Why? (`TimeZoneInfo.IsDayLigtSavingTime()` returns true from *30-03-1959*)

The following is the sample code to reproduce;

```
            //option 1: without timezone info but system date and time set to GMT Standard Time
            DateTime orgDateTime1 = new DateTime(1959, 04, 12, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime timeUtc1 = orgDateTime1.ToUniversalTime();

            //option 2: with timezone and system date and time set to GMT Standard Time
            TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
            DateTime orgDateTime2 = new DateTime(1959, 04, 12, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime timeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(orgDateTime2, gmtZone);
```

Comment: The bottom line is that many countries have messed around with both their standard and DST offsets over the years, altering the start and end dates and the amount of the offset (the [UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) had a lot of changes around 1940 to 1980). If you get such differences, start looking for historic changes for offsets for standard and daylight saving time at an appropriate location.

Comment: Thank you. So how to handle this situation. Is any bug from c# when converting to UTC ? (I mean which does not have this history?)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues going on.

- The offset provided by Chrome and other modern browsers for `1959-04-11T23:00:00Z` is `+00:00` and that is *correct*.  In 1959, BST (UTC+1) started on April 19th.  Internet Explorer is incorrect - more on this below.
- The display name "British Summer Time" is *incorrect* for that date.  It should say "Greenwich Mean Time".  This is due to [bug 10068](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=10068) in the V8 JavaScript engine, which affects Chrome, Edge, and Node.js. This bug does not occur in FireFox.

For reference, see the following charts from [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=1959&syear=1958&eyear=1961):

[image: 1959 Time Zones - London]

[image: Time zone changes in London from 1958 through 1961]

The reason the offset shows incorrectly as `+01:00` in *Internet Explorer* is because unlike modern browsers, IE doesn't use the historical data of the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  Instead, it relies only on the time zone data in the Windows registry, which does not contain the *full* history of changes for all time zones.

For the UK time zone, the Windows registry only has one DST rule - the one that has *actually* been observed since 1996.  UK's DST changes before 1996 are suspect since they may have followed different rules in reality.

Thus, your assertion about correct/incorrect between browsers is inverted.  It's the modern browsers that are showing the correct offset, while Internet Explorer is incorrect due to a known issue.

Also, just an aside, but you should not directly call `console.log` on a `Date` object.  That behavior is undefined by both the ECMAScript specification and the WhatWG Console specification.  Some implementations will give the local time output as if you called `toString` on the object, and other implementations will give the UTC output as if you called `toISOString` on the object.  It's better to log the output of one of those functions yourself, such that you don't encounter inconsistencies between implementations.

Comment: thank you. I will check with this constraints. So new Date(utc date) is correct way to convert to local time ?

Comment: No.  `new Date(...)` constructs a `Date` object given some input.  A `Date` object is *always* UTC based.  The input to the constructor may or may not be UTC, and the output of a function may or may not be UTC, but the object itself always is.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest the better approach to convert to local date?

Comment: Actually the scenario is an interesting one. The application (.NET MVC)  database table maintains date as local date (instead of UTC). In the MVC controller the local date converted to UTC an sent to the javascript. I understood the timzone details you told. If so why the c# substract 1 hour while converting to UTC.

Comment: I updated the original question with server side conversion

Comment: Hi.   Please don't keep tacking on new questions to an already asked and answered question.  The first question you asked was only about the browser and not related at all to server-side code or .NET.  You should revert your edit, then go ask a new question about that part.  Thanks.

Comment: British DST between about 1940 and 1980 was a basket case. I have no doubt it will continue to mess with both DST and standard offsets, if for no other reason than to piss–off the EU. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see error (i am from france), be careful too with the time change between winter and summer implemented in system...

```html
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var utcDate1 = new Date("1960-04-11T23:00:00Z"); // utc date returned from server
            var utcDate2 = new Date("1959-04-11T23:00:00Z");
            var localDate1 = new Date(utcDate1);
            var localDate2 = new Date(utcDate2);            
            console.log(localDate1, localDate2)
            document.getElementById('dValue1').innerText = localDate1 ;
            document.getElementById('dValue2').innerText = localDate2;

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Your Date is <span id="dValue1"></span></p>
    <p>Your Date is <span id="dValue2"></span></p>    
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please confirm which browser you tired. I just run your code and got same issue for the second date. I am little confused now. My system timezone is "(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"

Comment: @Akhil tested on Firefox and chrome....(last version)

Comment: K but why it is happened to me. I don't know any system related. But your code also same behaviour for.me

Comment: you have to considered also the time change between summer/winter...and maybe at this date there are somes changes in your country?  and i am pretty sure its in the system..

Comment: Yes . Actually i can get this difference in dst on. I assume if we convert utc to local time it will handle that. Take the first example its handled that correctly but the issue for year less that 1960 .

Comment: The location is important. The OP has "British Summer Time" so likely a location like "Europe/London", which has different historic offsets to France, though they were likely coordinated in recent years.